# Why does my java application run slow when using fiddler?

Tags: java, web-services, fiddler

I have a java application launched via java web start.

I'm using fiddler to debug some web service calls, but when the calls are running through fiddler, the application runs much slower.

There doesn't seem to be any CPU bottleneck, and the I don't think the messages are huge.

Any idea what could be slowing it down?

thanks,
Mark

Comment: Maybe you should tune fiddler somehow? Have you checked [Fiddler2 FAQ](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/faq.asp)?

Comment: What are the timings shown on the Statistics tab?